# Camera Preview App in Android throwing many errors (Nexus 4)

Tags: java, android, camera, android-sqlite, preview

I am trying to develop a camera app that takes a picture and saves it in a SQLite database. I get a lot of errors when executing the application. My code is as below. Any idea?

CameraActivity.java

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private int CAMERA_RETURN_CODE=100;
private static final String TAG = "Take_Picture";
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private Bitmap cameraBmp;
private int MAX_FACES = 1;
private Face[] faceList;
public RectF[] rects;
private Canvas canvas;
private Drawable pictureDataDrawable;
private MySQLiteHelper database;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, 0, mCamera);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    database = new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            private PictureCallback mPicture;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //mCamera.startPreview();
                // get an image from the camera
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        try{
                            if (data != null)
                            database.addEntry(data);

                            //mCamera.startPreview();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){

                            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }


            }
        }
    );


}


/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(c.getNumberOfCameras()-1); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}


public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 360;
    /*switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }*/

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

public void startFaceDetection(){
    // Try starting Face Detection
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // start face detection only *after* preview has started
    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0){
        // camera supports face detection, so can start it:
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}
```

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private String TAG;
private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }


    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mCamera == camera) { return; }



    mCamera = camera;

    if (mCamera != null) {
        List<Size> localSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = localSizes;
        requestLayout();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
          Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must 
          be started before you can take a picture.
          */
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

MySQLiteHelper.java

```
private static final int count = 0;
 public static final String TABLE_IMAGE = "images";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String PICTURE_DATA = "picture";

  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "images.db";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_IMAGE + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PICTURE_DATA
          + " blob not null);";

  public static SQLiteDatabase database;
private static String TAG = "test";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
     database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_IMAGE);
            onCreate(db);

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addEntry(byte [] array) throws SQLiteException{

    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    //cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
    cv.put(PICTURE_DATA,   array);
    database.insert( TABLE_IMAGE, null, cv );
    Log.w(TAG , "added " +count+ "images");
    database.close();
}
```

Errors

```
11-07 23:28:39.050: E/mm-libcamera2(176): PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1383838119.067589459
11-07 23:28:39.050: E/mm-camera(201): config_MSG_ID_STOP_ACK: streamon_mask is not clear. Should not call PP_Release_HW
11-07 23:28:39.090: E/QCameraHWI(176): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*):Received Setting NULL preview window
11-07 23:28:39.090: E/QCameraHWI(176): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0x0, mStreamDisplay = 0x0xb8a9df90
11-07 23:28:39.090: E/mm-camera(201): config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning. 
11-07 23:28:39.090: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_ops_deinit: E
11-07 23:28:39.120: E/qcom_sensors_hal(533): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
11-07 23:28:39.310: E/qcom_sensors_hal(533): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
11-07 23:28:39.330: E/mm-camera(201): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx119_preview.so: 30
11-07 23:28:39.340: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_ops_init: E
11-07 23:28:39.360: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
11-07 23:28:39.360: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
11-07 23:28:39.360: E/mm-camera(201): mctl_init_stats_proc_info: snap_max_line_cnt =25776
11-07 23:28:39.440: E/QCameraHWI(176): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0xb8aa1780, mStreamDisplay = 0x0xb8a9df90
11-07 23:28:39.440: E/mm-camera(201): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_INFORM_STARTPREVIEW
11-07 23:28:39.450: E/mm-camera(201): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 1 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 810081 cid = 0
11-07 23:28:39.490: E/mm-camera(201): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 3 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 830083 cid = 0
11-07 23:28:39.490: E/mm-camera(201): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 4 as : width = 512, height 384, format = 1 inst_handle = 840084 cid = 0
11-07 23:28:39.500: E/mm-camera(201): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 3, Op mode 1
11-07 23:28:39.500: E/mm-camera(201): config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 0 Full size streaming : Disabled
11-07 23:28:39.500: E/mm-camera(201): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
11-07 23:28:39.500: E/mm-camera(201): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 3, Path: 4
11-07 23:28:39.510: E/mm-camera(201): config_update_inst_handles Updated the inst handles as 810081, 830083, 0, 0 
11-07 23:28:39.631: E/mm-camera(201): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx119_preview.so: 30
11-07 23:28:39.631: E/mm-camera(201): camif_client_set_params: camif has associated with obj mask 0x1
11-07 23:28:39.631: E/mm-camera(201): config_v2_CAMERA_START_common CAMIF_PARAMS_ADD_OBJ_ID failed -1 
11-07 23:28:39.641: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_operation_config: format 3
11-07 23:28:39.641: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=5
11-07 23:28:39.641: E/mm-camera(201): Invalid ASD Set Params Type
11-07 23:28:39.641: E/mm-camera(201): vfe_set_bestshot: Bestshot mode not changed
```

Comment: Do you get a black screen? a Crash?

Comment: nope. I don't get a black screen or crash

Comment: Ok but what's your current status? Do you see the camera preview? I'm not sure what's your problem.

Comment: The camera preview seems to work but I'm getting all this error message in eclipse logcat. I'm not sure where this errors come from.